# Email with image attachment not showing correctly on Outlook 2016 sent by python

Tags: python-3.x, email, email-attachments, python-3.8, smtplib

I am sending email with python, using the libs:

```
import smtplib, ssl, json
from email import encoders


from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid
import mimetypes

sender_email = 'sender@mydomain.com'
sender_pass = 'password'
receiver_email = 'receiver@mydomain.com'

message = EmailMessage()
message["Subject"] = "Alerta #"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email

# ADD TEXT
message.set_content(f'''TEXT EMAIL''')

# ADD HTML
figura_1_cid = make_msgid(domain='mydomain.com.br')
html = f'''
<div>
    <img width="500px" height="300px" id="Imagem001" src="cid:{ figura_1_cid[1:-1] }" alt="imagem1">
</div>
'''
message.add_alternative(html, subtype='html')

with open('path_to_img.jpg', "rb") as attachment:
    maintype, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(attachment.name)[0].split('/')
    name = attachment.name[attachment.name.rfind('/')+1:]
    message.add_attachment(attachment.read(), maintype=maintype, subtype=subtype, filename=name, cid=figura_1_cid)

context = ssl.create_default_context()
#try:
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.domain.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, sender_pass)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
```

This works fine with gmail and outlook web (for browser and mobile). However it does not show the images on Outlook 2016 for Desktop.

The image is shown as square with a red cross.

[image: Suqare with red X]

I checked the email and it has the following body:

```
        <div>
           =20
            <p><img src=3D"cid:165350088051.23608.15969424157401111621@grpa=
rceria.com.br"></p>
        </div>

--===============1407169985563985930==--
--===============7241407876403440948==
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="./uploads/60_foto1.jpg"
Content-ID: <165350088051.23608.15969424157401111621@domain.com.br>
MIME-Version: 1.0


--===============7241407876403440948==--
```

Can any one help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some e-mail clients handle attachment file location differently. This is the case for Win Desktop Outlook 2016 and Gmail mobile app, for exemple.

You may want to skip embedding attachment altogether and link the files using html href. This has two benefits, one is ease of implementing and another is compatibility with most modern clients (rendering html decently enough is very widespread)

Comment: Also, attempting to impose a directory name in the `filename=` is violating the recipient's filesystem integrity. You are only allowed to pass in a filename, not a path. (But if you want to access it from your HTML, probably use a `cid` instead. But then obviously you have to use the _correct_ `cid`, not a random different one.)